# Confidence interval for a proportion when sample proportion is almost 1 or 0

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion

I know there are methods to calculate a confidence interval for a proportion to keep the limits within (0, 1), however a quick Google search lead me only to the standard calculation: $\hat{p} \pm 1.96*\sqrt\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{N}$.  I also believe there is a way to calculate the exact confidence interval using the binomial distribution (example R code would be nice).  I know I can use the prop.test function to get the interval but I'm interested in working through the calculation.

Sample situations (N = number of trials, x = number of success):

```
N=40, x=40
N=40, x=39
N=20, x=0
N=20, x=1
```

Comment: Check out [this paper](http://www.ine.pt/revstat/pdf/rs080204.pdf). It doesn't give the R code you want, but it has many examples of nearly exact confidence intervals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Clopper-Pearson interval?

Wikipedia discribes how to do this here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

For example if you take your 39 successes in 40 trial example you get:

```
> qbeta(.025,39,2) #qbeta(alpha/2,x,n-x+1) x=num of successes and n=num of trials
[1] 0.8684141
> qbeta(1-.025,39,2)
[1] 0.9938864
```

For your 40 out of 40 you get:

```
> qbeta(1-.025,40,1)    
[1] 0.9993673
> qbeta(.025,40,1)
[1] 0.9119027
```

Comment: The Clopper-Pearson method is excessively conservative when the observed proportion approaches 0 or one. That conservatism is a consequence of them being designed for _at least_ 1-alpha covefrage in the long run rather than good performance for the particular data set being examined. See my answer to this question for more detail; http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/discrete-functions-confidence-interval-coverage/8860#8860

Comment: shouldn't it be `n-x+1` instead of what you have at the moment/

Answer (score 13):

There are many confidence intervals for single proportions and most of them have poor performance for $p$ close to 0 or 1. The "exact" Clopper-Pearson interval mentioned above is very conservative in that setting, meaning that the actual coverage of the interval can be quite a bit larger than the nominal $1-\alpha$.

An interval that has pretty good performance for $p$ close to 0 or 1 is actually the Bayesian credible interval using the Jeffreys prior. See e.g. [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2676784) by Brown, Cai and DasGupta (2002). It is simple to compute in R:

```
qbeta(c(alpha/2,1-alpha/2),x+0.5,n-x+0.5)
```

Nevermind that it is Bayesian by nature - it has been shown over and over again to have good *frequentist* performance!

(Although the Bayesian Jeffreys interval usually is recommended in this setting, it is possible to construct intervals that simultaneously give higher confidence and lower expected length for small $p$; see a recent [manuscript](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.5894) of mine.)

Comment: I a point about exact methods that should be noted is that in the hypothesis teting framework they produce a sawtoothed power function.  This is because of the discrete nature of random variable like the binomial.  It also leads to erratic behavior for confidence intervals.  A number of methods that smooth thing out have been proposed.  Lots of articles on this in the American Statistician including mine with Christine Liu and a comment on it by Jeff Longmate.

Comment: If the true p is not exactly 0 or 1 you will see this by taking a large sample (unless of course it si something like 0.999999.  In small samples getting all successes or all failures may not be a clear indication on the value of p, a general problem with small sample sizes.  But if p were equal to 0.5 n doesn't have to be very large for this to be a very unlikely event.  If the true p is close to 0 or 1 it would also be worth noting that the variance of the maximum likelihood estimate for p has a much smaller variance than if p were 0.5.

Comment: The paper as linked is not public. Here is a link to it https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1009213286

Comment: I assume you set the 'a' and 'b' parameters to 0.5 to be uniformed. What if we know that the successes are rare. Can we lower a in a fair way?

Comment: @Keith - a=b=0.5 corresponds to the Jeffreys prior. And yes, in a Bayesian context you can use other a and b to represent prior knowledge, e.g. low a and high b to indicate that successes are rare.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just do this in a Bayesian way?

That is, set up a beta-distributed prior, and choose some interval whose integral is as big as you want it (working out from the mode, for example).

Comment: +1 That is certainly a possibility.  But for now I'm interested in the frequentist methods.

Comment: Concur, the Bayesian approach is very simple for proportions, and gets directly at the salient aspect here which is the confidence interval can't go outside [0,1] and is likely asymmetrical.

Answer (score 4):

Clopper-Pearson is an exact binomial method and can be used to get confidence intervals for p even when the number of successes is 0 out of N or N out of N.  in the first case it will give an interval from 0 to A where A depends on N and alpha and from B to 1 in the latter case.

Comment: Speaking of CIs when the number of successes is 0 (out of N trials), I've always enjoyed the simplicity of the _"rule of three"_ http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2685405?uid=3738984&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21100794941751

Comment: Besides the reference that andrea gives the rule of three is described in van Belle's book "Statistical Rules of Thumb".  The book is delightful and very well-written and it explains the many statistical rules of thumb allowing you to understand how they came about and why they make sense.