# Why may one use qbeta() to calculate CIs for binomial proportions that are actually based on the F-distribution?

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

I just barely grasped why large-sample confidence limits that assume approximately normal distributions are not the best approach when relative frequencies approach either one or zero - so that in these instances methods according to Jeffrey or Clopper/Pearson are preferable, and can be calculated with relative ease using R's `qbeta()` (e.g. discussed here: [Confidence interval for a proportion when sample proportion is almost 1 or 0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/28316)).

Now wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) and others appear to claim that this is allowed due to some relationship between the F-distribution and the Beta-distribution, but I am struggling to follow either this argument or why it would allow using `qbeta()` instead of another (more complicated) parametrization of either `qf()` or `pf()`. Is there a rather straight explanation for this equivalence that a non-mathematician might follow?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) actually *defines* F in terms of the Beta distribution.

Comment: Right, thanks (but even that is currently too much of a wall of formulae for me).

Comment: You may be asking the impossible, then. Because this question comes down to the relationship between F and Beta distributions, in order to make it answerable, please give us your "non-mathematician" definition of these distributions and how they arise. After all, if no reasonably accurate definition is available that would meet your standards, than *a fortiori* there cannot possibly exist any explanation of the connection that would meet your standards, either.

Comment: I get the point. I figured F can be seen as a quotient between two Chi-squares (which should in turn be sums of squared normal distributions) - but my prerequisites about Beta are so hazy that I should have actually retreated to "Why can weird forms of F be used to compute CIs for binomial distributions?" (Naively assuming that there is an easily comprehensible explanation.)

Comment: Well, there are some geometric explanations--I just wanted to let you know that in case you would find such things accessible.  But I believe there's no avoiding mathematics, however you go about doing it, so if you don't want to reopen this question I'll understand.

Comment: I have reopened this at the request of a very respected community member who--although s/he did not promise anything--has shown themselves highly capable of providing an illuminating answer :-).