How to know what effect size is excluded by a negative trial
I am trying to get my head around how best to think about "negative" studies in Medicine. For background, I'm a medical doctor in Critical Care, not a statistician, and I'm not a researcher. My statistics education has mostly been Frequentist.
To make this concrete I've been reading the VASST trial (free full text) which compares different drugs used to support peoples' blood pressure during sepsis looking (primarily) for a 28-day mortality benefit. This seems like a well designed and conducted trial that failed to show a difference in outcome according to their prespecified definition of statistical significance. Well that's lovely, but to my naïve way of thinking there are two possibilities:

There really is no difference
We have lost a potentially clinically significant difference due to a lack of power

Most of my reading so far focusses on trials that achieve statistical significance. There isn't much guidance of what to do when they don't. Keeping it concrete, in the VASST trial they were looking for a 10% absolute difference & couldn't demonstrate that. However, vasopressin (the trial drug) is cheap, people aren't on it for very long & there are practical short-term benefits we see day-to-day - I would be interested in a much lesser difference (maybe as low as 2-5%) and, equally importantly, I want to know that we aren't missing harm.
So my question: what can we say about the effect size we have actually excluded? What remains plausible?
The absolute risk difference (and 95% CI) were 3.9% (-2.9 to 10.7). Intuitively it seems reasonable to make some statements like:

We are very sure the true effect is less than a 20% improvement
We are pretty sure the effect is (very?) likely to be less than 10%
We're much less sure where we stand with a 5% or lesser effect & we're pretty unsure about small levels of harm

Is there a way of being more precise about this?
Can I define some sort of plausible interval?
Can I plot a graph of effect size against plausibility? (& avoid using arbitrary thresholds like 0.05 defining significance)
I don't think confidence intervals directly answer this. I have calculated a reverse fragility index which suggests this is indeed a fragile result (for a 10% ARR) but that doesn't answer the questions above. Bayesian analysis keeps cropping up but I don't know where to start with that and I don't have patient level data to do reanalysis.

You might find this question and answers (mine particularly!) interesting: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40769/are-all-values-within-a-95-confidence-interval-equally-likely


what can we say about the effect size we have actually excluded? What remains plausible?

This link to Frank Harrell and others talking about how to interpret results from treatment effects is super helpful.  There are a variety of statements about "Negative" trials (Frank's quotations, not mine).
Were I to copy and paste some of the language from that post and apply it to your scenario, I might say
"If the true risk difference < -2.9, we’d almost never (0.025 of the time) expect a difference as large as we observed. Thus differences < -2.9 are contradicted by the data. If the true difference > 10.7. we’d almost never (0.025 of the time) expect a difference as small as we observed. Thus differences > 10.7 are contradicted by the data."
In addition to this, I might add that risk differences between -2.9 and 10.7 are all compatible with the data (for some definition of compatible).

Can I define some sort of plausible interval?

That would, more or less, be the confidence interval.  You'd have to explain a little more why you don't think a confidence interval gives you what you need.

Can I plot  a graph of effect size against plausibility? (& avoid using arbitrary thresholds like 0.05 defining significance)

This would require a Bayesian approach.  Were you to take it, then you could plot the posterior estimates of the risk difference.
Say I run a simple randomized trial.  Each group (treatment and control) as 200 patients.  Treatment has 25 outcomes while control has 18.  Using some well known results from Bayesian statistics, I can get a very simple posterior distribution for the risk difference.  It might look like the following

What I think you might want is to be able to put probability statements on effect sizes.  In theory, the posterior can allow you to do that.  For example, we can see that the posterior distribution has a lot of probability mass above 0, and not so much above 0.10.  Its natural to ask "what is the probability the effect is between 0 and 0.1", and in this case we would get an answer of "$85\%^1$". As we make that range shorter.
So you can convert your statements re: how sure you are that the effect is in some range into a probabilistic statement.


I've used a normal approximation for both posteriors.


Hi Demetri & thanks for that detailed answer. I'll see if I can formulate my concerns about CIs into something sensible. Your link is broken - it seems to point to a realtor site. Have you pasted the wrong link perhaps?

@DrDogg Oops, link fixed.  Thank you!

It's probably worth noting that the likelihood function will allow the same interpretation as your posterior with unspecified prior.

@MichaelLew - I can see you commented on both answers. Thanks for the thoughtful contribution. Would you be willing to expand on the purpose of the likelihood function? I might be a useful addition. (Don't worry if not - you've given me a helpful start for something to Google)

@DemetriPananos - Frank Harrell seems to discuss exactly the thoughts I've been having. Thanks for that - it has put me on a very useful track. In terms of my concerns about CIs, your link describes it well in on of his examples: "The observed B-A difference in means was -4mmHg with a 0.95 confidence interval of [-13, 5]. If this study could be indefinitely replicated and the same approach used to compute a confidence interval each time, 0.95 of such varying confidence intervals would contain the unknown true difference in means. Based on the current study, the probability...

...that the true difference is within [-13, 5] is either zero or one, i.e., we cannot interpret the interval except for its properties in the long run.". While correct, this doesn't seem a very helpful statement. I note the alternatives that you and he provide though.

Going back to yourt 2 possibilities:
1. There really is no difference
2. We have lost a potentially clinically significant difference due to a lack of power
It really is not quite that; in fact it is simpler to interpret negative results: only 1 possibility
Whatever effect there was, the study was underpowered to detect it
which can be rephrased, for a properly designed study, as
There is no clinically significant difference
Regarding your first option, as a general rule, in applied statistics, there is always a difference. It may be very small, so ridiculously small that no one would care, but there is a difference. The probability that 2 drugs (unless they are both placebo) behave in exactly the same way (same effect, same side effects, sake pharmacokinetics, etc.) is really 0. So there is a difference, but maybe not one we would care about.
Regarding your 2nd possibility, the study in question appears to be properly powered to detect an effect of 10% or more (note that the upper bound of the CI is 10.7, close to 10). Now you say that you would care for an effect as low as 2-5%; this is a debate you would need to pick with your fellow MD's, as to why they picked 10%. Statisticians can not determine what the clinical consensus should be, they can only implement it.
In terms of power, just as a corner of the enveloppe calculation, and as an order of magnitude calculation, say the study had quadrupled the sample size. One would expect the CI's width to be, roughly, halved ($\frac {1} {\sqrt 4}$); (.5, 7.5), still centered at 3.9%. Still not significant for >10, or even >5. So, again, the study had good power.
So in the end, at least for this one study, there is only 1 possibility: The effect was smaller than the authors felt was the minimally clinically significant effect, which the study was properly powered to detect.
One question I have is why the authors chose to use a double-sided CI; they are trying to show that the trial drug is superior to the standard of care; they should have used a single sided CI (low bound only; where is the harm if the risk factor is even more positive?). Now, this would not have changed the conclusion of the original trial (no chance that the low bound is > 10%). But for the "imaginary" trial, with 4x the sample size, one may have been able to show that the risk factor was statistically >0, maybe at 1 or 2%. This may be a small effect, but if there are no side effect, counterindications, cost issues, etc., why not take it?

"the study in question appears to be properly powered" The study was designed to have 0.8 power to detect a difference of 10% at day 28 "assuming a mortality rate of 60% in the norepinephrine group". Three problems with your "properly powered": (i) @DrDogg appears to be interested in a smaller effect; (ii) that rate of martality was not achieved (good for patients, bad for the power); (iii) the conventional 0.8 power versus a 5% two-sided false positive rate is conventional but favours the negative outcome.

...cont. Final issue is that the effect was greater at 90 days than at 28. The study provides excellent preliminary information for a better designed follow-up. The all-or-none significant/not significant dichotomisation strikes again as a poor way to do science.

A few reasons why I say it seems properly powered. 1) 10 is at the upper end of the CI; with just a bit more power, they would even have been able to reject 10 as a possible effect 2) Even with 4x the sample size (and some hand waving), they would not have been able to get a significant result, and in fact would have been able to definitively exclude 10 3) As powered, a single sided upper bound CI may have been able to reject 10 (tbd, based on exact data, but would be close).  I do however your dislike of the traditional 80% power; one is setting oneself up for a negative outcome indeed.

Post-data power is not a reliable indication of the design power...

@jginestet Thanks for the reply. I take your point that a genuine no-effect case is not real - I was speaking crudely and I might have phrased it better. Thanks for clarifying.

@jginestet In terms of the effect seen in VASST: (1) we are fortunate in Critical Care that we are entering an era of much larger trials - 3000 patient trials (or more in some cases) are no longer unusual thanks to groups such as the ANZICS CTG. This topic has not been tested in such a trial yet however. (2) We have a real problem in medicine of people being overly optimistic about effect sizes - in critical care 10% effect sizes are very rare indeed. The problem that (frequently) follows in that people confuse absence of evidence with evidence of absence, hence my question
