# Basic easy rules for statistics

Tags: rule-of-thumb

In a binomial experiment, if we observe $x=0$ positive individual among $n$ individuals, then the proportion of positive individuals is significantly lower than $3/n$ with a type 1 error less than and very close to $5\%$. This fact, sometimes called the "rule of three", is a consequence of the inequalities $$\exp\left(-\frac{np}{1-p}\right) \leq \Pr(X=0) \leq \exp(-np).$$

Do you know other such basic easy rules for statistics? I find them very interesting and useful. This principle is not really a "rule of thumb" because it has a reliable theoretical foundation, but I don't see another tag for this question (I hope it is not off-topic)

Comment: "Normally, more than two-thirds of the people are average" (meaning within one standard deviation of the mean)?

Comment: One very simple one that comes to mind is how the variance of a sample proportion of successes out of $n$ Bernoulli trials is no more than $1/4n$ (which is achieved when the success probability is $1/2$)

Comment: Many "rules of thumb" are based on theoretically rigorous analyses or approximations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out Gerald van Belle's book ["Statistical Rules of Thumb"](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=statistical+rules+of+thumb&sprefix=Statistical+ru%2Cstripbooks%2C178) a very nice little paperback text loaded with examples of rules of thumb and explanations including the "Rule of three" that you mention above.

Comment: (+1) That seems like a nice book. Not only does he give rule-of-thumbs, but he also motivates them and discuss their validity.

Comment: Nice! I will ask to my boss to buy it :)

Comment: Ahah ! I've just send an email to my boss and actually we already have this book :)

Comment: Yes, it's a great book.  It's fun just to read it.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/rules-of-thumb-for-modern-statistics?rq=1

Comment: So Stephane.  It looks like someone else knowing about the book asked this question and got a variety of answers.